# Send images to printer as they are uploaded from camera

Tags: python, image, printing

I need to ask my computer to print automatically images as they arrive from a camera.

A friend of mine suggested this code

```
monRep = "/**/Desktop/DATA/"
import os, mimetypes, random

fpaths = []
for fname in os.listdir(monRep):
    fpath = os.path.join(monRep, fname)
    if os.path.isfile(fpath):
        mt = mimetypes.guess_type(fpath)[0]
        ext = os.path.splitext(fpath)[1]
        if mt: mt = mt.split('/')[0].lower()
        else: mt = False
        #if ext.lower() in ('.bmp','.pict', '.JPG', '.jpg'): mt = 'image'
        if mt in ('image',): fpaths.append(fpath)

choix = random.choice(fpaths)
command = "lpr "+choix
print (command)
os.system(command)
```

It works, but just for one image. I need to print all the images.

Here is my idea

1. Check folder "DATA"
2. Find Image1
3. Print Image1
4. Pause 30 sec (to wait for the next image)
5. Repeat step 1

Comment: `os.listdir(monRep)` will *not* work unless you have an actual directory called `/**`... I'll presume you elided a path there. :-)

Comment: Off course, I put a real path...

Comment: Have you actually tried to implement your idea?

Answer (score 2):

So, instead of this code that prints one random photo

```
choix = random.choice(fpaths)
command = "lpr "+choix
print (command)
os.system(command)
```

You want to print them all, just write a loop:

```
for fpath in fpaths:
    command = "lpr "+fpath
    print (command)
    os.system(command)
```

And I would recommend moving the file to a new folder so you don't get duplicate prints next time this is run:

```
for fpath in fpaths:
    newpath = fpath.replace('/DATA/','/DONE/')
    os.rename(fpath,newpath)
    command = "lpr "+newpath
    print (command)
    os.system(command)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Python told me

    TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Any idea ?

Comment: doublecheck that you copied it verbatim - it's being called with two arguments in my example code.  Make sure those single quotes didn't get mangled by your editor maybe?

Comment: Thanks very much it works. All the images are printed at once. But I'd like them to be printed as far as they arrive in the initial folder... How can I ask the programm to repeat itself after a while (let's say 2 minutes for example). Thanks again for you help !